# how to include factories inside the ts file in angular 8

Tags: angular8, angular-providers, angular-factory

I have this factory which has ngx-timpicker factory.ts , i want to include it in my ts file to use the factory in my time.ts file , but I am getting error in my import line in time.ts file that error -

```
TS2305: Module '"../../factories/timepickerconfig.factory"' has no exported member 'TimepickerConfig'.

7 import { TimepickerConfig } from '../../factories/timepickerconfig.factory';
           ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

    import { TimepickerConfig } from '../../factories/timepickerconfig.factory';
```

how to import the factories in ts file

factory/timepickerconfig.factory.ts

```
import { TimepickerConfig } from 'ngx-bootstrap/timepicker';

useFactory: () => {
    const timepickerConfig = new TimepickerConfig();
    timepickerConfig.hourStep = 2;
    timepickerConfig.minuteStep = 10,
    timepickerConfig.showMeridian = false,
    timepickerConfig.readonlyInput = false,
    timepickerConfig.mousewheel = true,
    timepickerConfig.showMinutes = true,
    timepickerConfig.showSeconds = false
  }
```

time.ts

```
import { TimepickerConfig } from '../../factories/timepickerconfig.factory';

@Component({
  selector: 'time',
  templateUrl: './time.html',
  styleUrls: ['./time.scss'],
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None,
  providers: [
    { provide: TimepickerConfig, useFactory: TimepickerConfig },
    { provide: DateAdapter, useClass: MomentDateAdapter, deps: [MAT_DATE_LOCALE] },
    { provide: MAT_DATE_FORMATS, useValue: MAT_MOMENT_DATE_FORMATS }]
})
```

Comment: what is the error? and what is the expected result?

Comment: I couldnt inject that factory file in my ts file, included the error

Comment: what is the content of `timepickerconfig.factory`?

Comment: included in factory/timepickerconfig.factory.ts

Comment: TimepickerConfig is not exported from that file. so you will not be able to import it